# How can I reduce the size of this file to 83 bytes or less?

Tags: optimization, reduce

Task description:
Create the divisibility function, which expects an array of integers and its size as a parameter. The function returns how many numbers divisible by two are in the array!

We want to save on the available storage space, so our source code can be a maximum of 83 bytes!

My current code:

```
int oszthatosag(int a[], int s){int r=0,i;for (i = 0; i < s; ++i)if(a[i] % 2 == 0)++r;return r;}
```

has a size of 96 bytes. I deleted all the unnecessary whitespaces and reduced the lenghths of the variables to a minimum, but it still doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: There are still many useless spaces and the function name can be shortened.

Comment: By the way, I don't believe that this is a real question. Rather a quiz. The length of the source code is irrelevant, as C/C++ is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove additional spaces, use a branch-less strategy to remove the `if`, move the initialization/increment of `i` outside the loop, and decrease `r` starting from `s` so to remove the `==0`. The resulting code should not only be shorter, but also faster. This assumes `s>=0` (otherwise `r` is smaller than expected).
Here is the final result:

```c
int oszthatosag(int a[],int s){int r=s,i=0;while(i<s)r-=a[i++]&1;return r;}
```

As pointed out by @Brendan, here is an even shorter version (still assuming `s>=0`):

```c
int oszthatosag(int a[],int s){int r=s;while(s)r-=a[--s]&1;return r;}
```

Note that in C, the default return type is `int` so you can omit it (required in C++). This is generally not a good idea (and cause compiler warnings), but it is shorter:

```c
oszthatosag(int a[],int s){int r=s;while(s)r-=a[--s]&1;return r;}
```

Comment: A bit-wise comparison (instead of the Mod) might be faster still (I don't know if the Mod operator is optimised for the case of 2):  `r-=a[i++]&1`

Comment: Compilers are able to optimize this easily if `a` is an `unsigned int` which is not the case here. Otherwise, it is indeed faster. The result is not the same for negative numbers but I guess it matches with the OP intent as long as the binary representation is C2 (which is the case on all standard platforms nowadays). Thank you.

Comment: Do you need `i`? Could be `while(s){ r-=a[--s]&1;}` if you don't need to worry about the caller giving you a negative `s`.

Comment: @Brendan Indeed, good point. I was already assuming `s>=0` anyway.